# Agent's public facing names

Tags: salesforce1-app

Is it possible to set Agents' public-facing names on Live Agent to be different from their Salesforce user names?

This is primarily to avoid agents being subjected to unwanted attention. At the moment we have had to adjust their usernames to help them avoid this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a field called *Custom Agent Name* in the *Live Agent Configurations* settings. You can set this field's value to show up as Agent's name in the chat window.

You can set the agent name which can be a static/anonymized name, or you can use User object merge fields to construct a name from user custom fields like agent alias, etc.